# Reproject and crop Sentinel imagery

Tags: gdal, google-maps, sentinel-2

I have a Sentinel 2A scene (downloaded from [Sentinel AWS storage](http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#tiles/38/U/LD/2017/5/31/0/) in UTM projection) and coordinates (a polygon of lat/lng) of a specific plot of land. How can I extract a piece corresponding to that field (preferably in EPSG 3857, so that I could overlay it on Google Maps) a piece corresponding to my plot of interest (or to a given Google Maps tile), using either Python or CLI tools?

I have used `gdalwarp` to transform the scene image to EPSG:3857, but how can I then transform the lat/lng coordinates of my plot's borders (or the given tile's borders) to the coordinates of the pixels I need to crop? Are there any ready-made utilities or libraries for that?

Comment: What format is your "polygon of lat/lng" in? Do you simply have a set of coordinates, or do you have a shp / kml / kmz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a rectangle bounding box you want to cut, you can use [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) function with target extents (-te) and target extent srs (-te_srs) :

> **-te xmin ymin xmax ymax**: set georeferenced extents of output file to be created (in target SRS by default, or in the SRS specified with
> -te_srs)
>
> **-te_srs srs_def**:
> (GDAL >= 2.0) Specifies the SRS in which to interpret the coordinates given with -te. The srs_def may be any of the usual GDAL/OGR forms, complete WKT, PROJ.4, EPSG:n or a file containing the WKT. This must not be confused with -t_srs which is the target SRS of the output dataset. -te_srs is a convenience e.g. when knowing the output coordinates in a geodetic long/lat SRS, but still wanting a result in a projected coordinate system.

For example:

```
gdalwarp -te 10 40 15 45 -te_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 infile outfile
```